# text on the background image in table

Tags: html

i have a problem in that i set a img as a background to a table , 
see below

```
        <table id ='outertable' style="background: url(courierimages/biglogo.jpg) no-repeat center;opacity:0.2;filter:alpha(opacity=20);">
    <tr>
     <td>
             <table id = 'innertable'>
        <tr>
              <td><input type = "text"></td>
                       </tr>
         </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here the opacity applies to the inner table too. But i need it for outertable only.Please guide on this , Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The opacity applied on parent element will be always inherited by it's children.

There are some [hacks that works with IE](http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/overriding-the-parent-propagation-of-alpha-transparency-filter-of-child-elements-in-internet-explorer/), but it's not a good solution...

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set a background-color on your inner table using css eg. add following to your stylesheet

```
#innertable background-color:#fff
```